# API JSON callback issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I have a simple input field that brings back shows as you search for them, using the Trakt API. Recently they changed their API and now my code no longer works (it used to). I’m getting this issue:

`Refused to execute script from http://.... because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

CODE:

```
  $.ajax ({
    type: "GET",
    // **OBSOLETE** url: 'http://api.trakt.tv/search/shows.json/78c0761c9409a61cf88e675687d6f790/'+ value +'/5/seasons/',
    url: 'http://api.trakt.tv/search/shows.json/78c0761c9409a61cf88e675687d6f790?query=' + value + '&limit=5&seasons=true',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    json: "callbackname",
    crossDomain : true,
```

If I remove:

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

or change to:

```
dataType: "json",
```

I get a different error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

**Demo:** http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48552248/websites/tiii.me/index.html (‘load unsafe script’ if https:// is forced)

**Link to code:** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48552248/websites/tiii.me/scripts/partials/_tv-show.js

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: just because an API serves JSON it doesn't mean it is CORS enabled or that it will serve jsonp. Read the API docs and if neither approach is available use a proxy.

Comment: try setting the options properly. read the ajax docs

Comment: you could even create your own proxy with php and return json or jsonp at your convenience

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {

    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
               || document.documentElement;

    window[ud] = function(data) {
        head.removeChild(script);
        success && success(data);
    };

    script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
    head.appendChild(script);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the response you are getting is not a jsonp response but a json response. In jsonp you should get a javascript method callback. Whereas in your case its plain json data. so you need to process the json data and manually call the callbackname method and pass the object that you are getting back as json result.

Comment: If I change to `json` I’m getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access.`